# Finding Depth of Binary Tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I am having trouble understanding this maxDepth code. Any help would be appreciated. Here is the snippet example I followed.

```
int maxDepth(Node *&temp)
{
  if(temp == NULL)
  return 0;

 else
{
 int lchild = maxDepth(temp->left);
 int rchild = maxDepth(temp->right);

 if(lchild <= rchild)
 return rchild+1;

 else
  return lchild+1;

 }
```

}

Basically, what I understand is that the function recursively calls itself (for each left and right cases) until it reaches the last node. once it does, it returns 0 then it does 0+1. then the previous node is 1+1. then the next one is 2+1. if there is a bst with 3 left childs, int lchild will return 3. and the extra + 1 is the root. So my question is, where do all these +1 come from. it returns 0 at the last node but why does it return 0+1 etc. when it goes up the left/right child nodes? I don't understand why. I know it does it, but why?

Comment: Euh, because if there's a new node, then the depth is the previous plus one, perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember in binary trees a node has at most 2 children (left and right)

It is a recursive algorithm, so it calls itself over and over.

If the temp (the node being looked at) is null, it returns 0, as this node is nothing and should not count. that is the base case.

If the node being looked at is not null, it may have children. so it gets the max depth of the left sub tree (and adds 1, for the level of the current node) and the right subtree (and adds 1 for the level of the current node). it then compares the two and returns the greater of the two.

It dives down into the two subtrees (temp->left and temp->right) and repeats the operation until it reaches nodes without children. at that point it will call maxDepth on left and right, which will be null and return 0, and then start returning back up the chain of calls.

So if you you have a chain of three nodes (say, root-left1-left2) it will get down to left2 and call maxDepth(left) and maxDepth(right). each of those return 0 (they are null). then it is back at left2. it compares, both are 0, so the greater of the two is of course 0. it returns 0+1. then we are at left1 - repeats, finds that 1 is the greater of its left n right (perhaps they are the same or it has no right child) so it returns 1+1. now we are at root, same thing, it returns 2+1 = 3, which is the depth.

Answer (score 8):

Consider this part (of a bigger tree):

```
       A
        \
         B
```

Now we want to calculate the depth of this treepart, so we pass pointer to `A` as its param.

Obviously pointer to `A` is not `NULL`, so the code has to:

- call `maxDepth` for each of `A`'s children (left and right branches). `A->right` is `B`, but `A->left` is obviously `NULL` (as `A` has no left branch)
- compare these, choose the greatest value
- return this chosen value + 1 (as `A` itself takes a level, doesn't it?)

Now we're going to look at how `maxDepth(NULL)` and `maxDepth(B)` are calculated.

The former is quite easy: the first check will make `maxDepth` return 0. If the other child were `NULL` too, both depths would be equal (0), and we have to return 0 + 1 for `A` itself.

But `B` is not empty; it has no branches, though, so (as we noticed) its depth is 1 (greatest of 0 for `NULL`s at both parts + 1 for `B` itself).

Now let's get back to `A`. `maxDepth` of its left branch (`NULL`) is 0, `maxDepth` of its right branch is 1. Maximum of these is 1, and we have to add 1 for `A` itself - so it's 2.

The point is the same steps are to be done when `A` is just a part of the bigger tree; the result of this calculation (2) will be used in the higher levels of `maxDepth` calls.

Answer (score 5):

Depth is being calculated using the previous node + 1

Answer (score 4):

All the ones come from this part of the code:

```
if(lchild <= rchild)
    return rchild + 1;
else
    return lchild + 1;
```

You add yourself `+1` to the results obtained in the leaves of the tree. These ones keep adding up until you exit all the recursive calls of the function and get to the root node.

Answer (score 2):

Because the depth is calculated with previous node+1

Answer (score 0):

To find Maximum depth in binary tree keep going left and Traveres the tree, basically perform a [DFS](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4bncAOf4XkM)
 or 
We can find the depth of the binary search tree in three different recursive ways

```
– using instance variables to record current depth and total depth at every level
– without using instance variables in top-bottom approach
– without using instance variables in bottom-up approach
```

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet can be reduced to just:

```
int maxDepth(Node *root){
    if(root){ return 1 + max( maxDepth(root->left), maxDepth(root->right)); }
    return 0;
}
```

A good way of looking at this code is from the top down:

What would happen if the BST had no nodes? We would have `root = NULL` and the function would immediately return an expected depth of `0`.

Now suppose the tree was populated with a number of nodes. Starting at the top, the `if` condition would be `true` for the root node. We then ask, what is the max depth of the LEFT SUB TREE and the RIGHT SUB TREE by passing the root of those sub trees to `maxDepth`. Both the LST and the RST of the root are **one level deeper** than the root, so we must add one to get the depth of the tree **at** `root` of the tree passed to the function.

Comment: wrong it would be like  int maxDepth(Node *root){
    if(root){ return 1 + max( maxDepth(root->left), maxDepth(root->right)); }
    return -1;
}

Answer (score 0):

i think this is the right answer

```
int maxDepth(Node *root){
    if(root){ return 1 + max( maxDepth(root->left), maxDepth(root->right)); }
    return -1;
}
```